# unable to generate app-specific shared secret

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

iTunesconnect post on 6/21/17 states that an app offering auto-renewable subscriptions can be transferred to a different developer by generating an app-specific shared secret. I followed the instructions up to "5. Click Generate App-Specific Shared Secret."  I got a message flashing on the screen that says "We cannot process your request." itunesconnect toll-free number is not answering because it is the weekend. I will try on Monday but meanwhile I wonder if anyone has had this problem and resolved it?

Comment: I saw this yesterday and today as well. At this point I'm guessing its iTunes being down? Make sure all your contracts are up to date and in effect as well.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing as well. Unfortunately, this is preventing me from implementing auto-recurring subscriptions as well.

Answer (score 1):

I sent an email yesterday about the link not working (probably has nothing to do with it being fixed..) and this morning was working. Just refresh the page and try again.